# declaring array as public in main and accessing it in other class

Tags: java

I want to know how to create/declare the array as public in main class and then access it in other class. The few lines of code of my programs are:

#### Main Class

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 

public class enc2kTest 
{   
  public static int[] msgArray = {14555256, 78925654, 76543878, 65432567, 76175544}; 

  public static void main(String ar[]) 
  { 
    --------- 
    --------- 
  } 
}
```

#### Other class accessing array

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 

public class inter1 
{   
  public static void main(String ar[]) 
  { 
    enc2kTest e2k = new enc2kTest(); 
    System.out.println(""); 
    for(int i = 0; i < e2k.msgArray.length; i++ ) 
    { 
      System.out.print(" | "); 
      System.out.print(e2k.msgArray[i]); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

but it displays the results as zero's. Why is that?

#### Output:

```
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: It works! Printing the contents of your `static` array. Not sure, why it doesn't work for you!

Comment: Can you post your output??

Comment: And you do not need to create an instance of enc2kTest as you are accessing a static member

Comment: output is:                                                            | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

Comment: I don't understand how that could be your output - you only have five elements in your array. Have you shown us the code you're actually running, or a simplification?

Comment: @numan09 how do you compile and run your codes?

Comment: The code you've posted is not the 1 you've used to get the above output. Post the code you're using to get the above output!

Comment: Unless your JVM has been possessed by some EVIL, you shouldn't get 0s as your output after running that code.

Comment: @numan09 Consider providing [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

The code in itself looks correct, but you need to recompile *all* classes that you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

copy/pasted your code

works fine for me

output:

```
 | 14555256 | 78925654 | 76543878 | 65432567 | 76175544
```